# Graylog in Kubernetes (1.20) cluster

Tags: kubernetes, graylog

I try to set up [graylog](https://github.com/mouaadaassou/K8s-Graylog/).
This deploy works. But i need to add a volume to graylog deploy. Because I want to install plugins.
When i add volume (hostPath) and start pod, I get an error in my pod:

```
ERROR StatusLogger File not found in file system or classpath: /usr/share/graylog/data/config/log4j2.xml
ERROR StatusLogger Reconfiguration failed: No configuration found for '70dea4e' at 'null' in 'null'
06:37:19.707 [main] ERROR org.graylog2.bootstrap.CmdLineTool - Couldn't load configuration: Properties file /usr/share/graylog/data/config/graylog.conf doesn't exist!
```

I see, that pod create catalogues (owner id 1100:1100) in volume, but there is no any file there.

Kubernetes version is 1.20
Runtime in my kubernetes cluster is "containerd".

My Graylog dеploy:

1. Volume ounys for container:

---

```
volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /usr/share/graylog/data
      name: graylog-data
```

2. Volume:

---

```
 volumes:
  - name: graylog-data
    hostPath:
      path: /mnt/k8s-storage/graylog-data
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
```

Comment: Welcome to the Stack udg :) The `type` of your volume is suspicious. Could you try with `file` instead of `DirectoryOrCreate`? I am investigating further in the meantime.

Comment: I find other decision. I use emptyDir volume. Within init container I download plugin for Graylog and doesn't have any volume yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few things to look at here starting from the concept of the [hostPath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath) volume:

> A `hostPath` volume mounts a file or directory from the host node's
> filesystem into your Pod.
>
> Pods with identical configuration (such as created from a PodTemplate)
> may behave differently on different nodes due to different files on
> the nodes
>
> The files or directories created on the underlying hosts are only
> writable by root. You either need to run your process as root in a
> privileged Container or modify the file permissions on the host to be
> able to write to a `hostPath` volume

The `hostPath` would be good if for example you would like to use it for log collector running in a `DaemonSet` but in your described use case it might not be ideal because you don't directly control which node your pods will run on, so you're not guaranteed that the pod will actually be scheduled on the node that has the data volume.

But if that not the case, you also need to notice that `type: DirectoryOrCreate` is not best here as I see that you want to load a file. It would be better to use either:

- `File`: A file must exist at the given path

or

- `FileOrCreate`: If nothing exists at the given path, an empty file will be created there as needed with permission set to 0644, having the same group and ownership with Kubelet.

Lastly, there might be a permissions problem. As already stated:

> The files or directories created on the underlying hosts are only
> writable by root.

Graylog is running with the [userid 1100](https://github.com/Graylog2/graylog-docker/blob/3.0/Dockerfile#L63) which might cause a permission denial. Also, I have found a [similar issue](https://github.com/Graylog2/graylog-docker/issues/76) that might be helpful for you.